# Try/catch block for simple memory allocation into public raw pointer when inside constructor?

Tags: c++, exception, pointers, constructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a case with a raw pointer that I can't change to a smart pointer because it is part of the interface (and I don't want to break any code using it):

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo();
  ~Foo();

  int * m_pStuff; // public!
};
```

I don't want to do much in my ctor. Just something like:

```
m_pStuff = new int[dynamically_obtained_size_which_is_greater_than_0];
m_pStuff[0] = 0;
```

And then in the destructor delete it.

Now, I wonder if it's really worth surrounding it with a try/catch:

```
Foo::Foo()
  : m_pStuff(0)
{
  try
  {
    m_pStuff = new int[dynamically_obtained_size_which_is_greater_than_0];
    m_pStuff[0] = 0;
  } 
  catch(...)
  {
    delete m_pStuff;
    throw;
  }
}
```

Points I can see against:

- More complex code
- Not really expecting any exception to happen there (unless it run out of space when allocating)
- Not really expecting the code to change

Points I can see for:

- Indicates to potential future coders that they should be careful with anything throwing exceptions and put it in the try block that is already in place
- If any exception does happen, memory release is taken care of

**I am quite undecided: should I surround this with a try/catch or not?** Why? I would like to get your opinions on that.

Also, **do you see any possibility of exception other then resulting from out of memory when allocating? And in that case the already allocated memory would be automatically reclaimed, right?**

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: I believe you should have `delete[] m_pStuff`, not `delete m_pStuff`.

Comment: True, thanks, I forgot that

Comment: @a1ex07: No, not really. `m_pStuff` is still `0` at that point in the code, so either `delete` or `delete[]` is precisely the same - a no-op. It would only make a difference if the allocation had succeeded... which it didn't!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No.

It's completely pointless.

`int` construction may not throw, so the only possible exception here is a `std::bad_alloc`. What are you doing in this case?

- Well, first you're doing `delete` on a NULL pointer, which is a no-op. The allocation failed, so you're not "reclaiming" anything.
- Then you're rethrowing the exception.

i.e. precisely what happens without the `try`/`catch`.

Just let the exception propagate, and document that it is possible.

*This advice does not necessarily apply to other types, though.*

---

**Also, don't forget your copy constructor.**

Comment: The core point here is that your failed `new` throws an exception, so `m_pStuff` never gets a chance to become anything other than the `0` to which you initialized it.

Comment: Sidenote: the whole thing changes when there's more than one pointer to allocate memory for. In that case I'd consider holding each allocation into `unique_ptr`'s or `boost::scoped_ptr`s and release them to the plain pointers after all allocations are done.

Comment: Yes - I'd avoid this use of raw pointers _altogether_, but that was cryptically ruled out by the OP.

Comment: Yes, of course I'd avoid them as well - my comment was just meant as "even if it's not that simple, prefer RAII exception handling over try-catch-rethrow"

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit what is cryptic about "raw pointer that I can't change to a smart pointer because it is part of the interface (and I don't want to break any code using it)"? If I changed the type of the pointer, there is client code that would be broken, because it is using this pointer and relying on it's type. Anyway, thanks for the answers.

Comment: @ricab: Cryptic is where you talked about the interface but then didn't demonstrate anything in which the pointer has anything to do with the interface, and where you didn't explain _why_ you're exposing implementation details in this manner.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I showed it was part of the class's interface when I put it public and added a comment drawing attention to this. And I am not exposing anything, this code is there already. There's probably no good reason for that, but that's irrelevant to the question...

Comment: @ricab: That's why I wrote it as a _comment_ and not an _answer_ ;)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Then the arbitrariness of your accusation of crypticism is limited to the comment scope ;)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is no need in try catch, since if you get std::bad_alloc in new pointer will be NULL and it will lead to delete NULL which will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

*Just additional information*

Throwing an exception from constructor is a potentially bad idea. Look at the code

```
class Foo
{
    Foo(int* a, int* b): _a(a), _b(b)
    {

    }

public:
    Foo() :
        Foo(nullptr, nullptr)
        // _a(nullptr), _b(nullptr)
    {
        _a = new int[10];
        _b = new int[100500 * 100500]; // should throw an exception
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        delete[] _a;
        delete[] _b;

        std::cout << "~Foo()" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int* _a;
    int* _b;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Foo f;
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Catched: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This code works as expected:

> ~Foo()
>   Catched: std::bad_alloc

But if we comment `Foo(nullptr, nullptr)` line and uncomment `// _a(nullptr), _b(nullptr)` line, we will see this output:

> Catched: std::bad_alloc

So, new code **does not call a destrutor**, since object is not fully constructed. We have a memory leak.

### What should you do to avoid it?

- Do not use a raw pointers, use smart pointers instead of it.
- Encapsulate one constructor into another, like in the first example.

Comment: or use a try/block... That much is clear, and the problem isn't the throwing of an exception from the destructor, is the untracked dynamic allocation of memory (which the smart pointer approach solves)

Comment: @ricab, I can't understand you. In your code you rethrow an exception from constructor, why're you talking about destructor now? Also, release memory in constructor is not idiomatically.

Comment: oops sorry, I meant constructor. Regarding memory release not being idiomatic, I don't agree. Memory release needs to happen in the ctor whenever memory allocation also happens before the ctor fails (when using a smart pointer that's exactly what you are ensuring). But remember that the smart pointer wasn't an option here (the raw pointer is already being used in other code that I can't touch)

Comment: @ricab, I understand you, but I have an another point of view to it. As for me, constructor is for creating objects, destructor is for destructing objects and we must not mix them.